# Editing Wordpress Nav Menu Walker

Tags: menus, css, walker

I have conntected T5_Nav_Menu_Walker to my WP website.
https://gist.github.com/thefuxia/1053467

And I want customize my WP menu to be able to add icons from wp-admin via FontAwesome classes. Screenshot: [Show](https://screenshots.firefox.com/lfGD5DWtdP901KuE/test12.md7.info)

But when I add CSS class in menu nothing outputting in HTML code, because I use t5_nav_walker. How I can add icons in this wordpress walker? Php code of this walker:

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Create a nav menu with very basic markup.
 *
 * @author Thomas Scholz http://toscho.de
 * @version 1.0
 */
class menu_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    /**
     * Start the element output.
     *
     * @param  string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @param  object $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param  int $depth     Depth of menu item. May be used for padding.
     * @param  array $args    Additional strings.
     * @return void
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args )
    {
        $output     .= '<li>';
        // $output .= '<li'.($item->current ? ' class="current"':'').'>';
        $attributes  = 'class="app-menu__item"';

        ! empty ( $item->attr_title )
            // Avoid redundant titles
            and $item->attr_title !== $item->title
            and $attributes .= ' title="' . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"';

        ! empty ( $item->url )
            and $attributes .= ' href="' . esc_attr( $item->url ) .'"';



        $attributes  = trim( $attributes );
        $title       = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );
        $item_output = "$args->before<a $attributes>$args->link_before$title</a>"
                        . "$args->link_after$args->after";

        // Since $output is called by reference we don't need to return anything.
        $output .= apply_filters(
            'walker_nav_menu_start_el'
            ,   $item_output
            ,   $item
            ,   $depth
            ,   $args
        );
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @return void
     */
    public function start_lvl( &$output )
    {
        $output .= '<ul class="treeview-menu">';
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @return void
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output )
    {
        $output .= '</ul>';
    }

    /**
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @param string $output Passed by reference. Used to append additional content.
     * @return void
     */
    function end_el( &$output )
    {
        $output .= '</li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you included your walker as parameter in wp_nav_menu() function?

Comment: Of course. And the walker works well. But this walker clears all default WP mynu styles and output only styles which is in this php code. And I can't output menu icons

Comment: Class on menu means in ul? You set static class. Or I’m miss understanding issue))

Comment: I have included this walker in functions & added it into menu area <ul class="app-menu">...</ul>   <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
      'theme_location' => 'main_menu',
      'menu_class' => 'app-menu',
      'link_before' => '<span class="app-menu__label">',     
      'link_after'  => '</span>',
      'walker'     => new menu_walker() ));
      ?>

Comment: You could also try the Menu Icons plugin. https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/menu-icons/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create additional field for menu item. Because if you will use class field - you will block adding additional class to links. 
But if it's ok - create `<i class="$your_class"></i>` before link title. And @Dilip Gupta gave solution to you.

Comment: I have added additional field via ACF and added Font Awesome classes in it. But! nothing outputting into <i class='" . $font_awesome = the_field('font_awesome') ."'></i>

Comment: `$item_output = "$args->before<a $attributes>$args->link_before$title</a>"
                        . "$args->link_after$args->after";` add your field value beetwen `$args->link_before` and `$title`.

Comment: `$font_awesome = the_field('font_awesome')` `the_field()` return nothing. Use `get_field()`

Comment: Somthing like this? . "<i class='" . $font_awesome = get_field('font_awesome') ."'></i>"

Comment: `"<i class='" . get_field('font_awesome') ."'></i>"` like this. Or assign `$font_awesome = get_field('font_awesome');` some earlier and use this:
`$font_awesome = get_field('font_awesome');`
`"<i class='" . $font_awesome ."'></i>"`

Comment: Small edit, may be for somebody will useful. To output acf custom field for menu item you must use $font_awesome = get_field('font_awesome', $item); instead $font_awesome = get_field('font_awesome');  Link - https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/adding-fields-menu-items/

Answer (score 1):

See, you need to update you `$item_output` variable. fontawesome outputs the icons in this format `<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>`.

you need to add this `<i>` within your `<a>` like this.

```
$item_output = "$args->before"
    . "<a $attributes>"
        . "$args->link_before"
        . "<i class='$variable_which_stores_fontawesomme_value'></i>"
        . "$title"
    . "</a>"
    . "$args->link_after"
    . "$args->after";
```

`$variable_which_stores_fontawesomme_value` should be equal to `fa fa-angle-right`.

Comment: I have added additional field via ACF and added Font Awesome classes in it. But! nothing outputting into <i class='" . $font_awesome = the_field('font_awesome') ."'></i>